# use values stored in varray sql-oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get my last 5 employees (ones with lowest salary) and raise their salary by 5%;
I am using a `varray` to store their id's but i don't know how to use those ids in a update statement (something like `update employees \ set salary = salary * 1.05 \ where id_employee in varray`)

here's what i have for now:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tip_cod IS VARRAY(20) OF NUMBER;
  coduri tip_cod;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO coduri
  FROM (
    SELECT employee_id
    from   employees
    where  commission_pct IS NULL
    order by salary asc
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM < 6;

  -- after i store their ids in coduri i want to update their salary
  FOR i IN 1 .. coduri.COUNT LOOP
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(coduri(i));
    
    
  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Why are you using an array for this? At an even higher level - why are you using PL/SQL for this? You can do the whole thing trivially in plain SQL.

Comment: I know, as an example i could just use nested statements, but i want to understand this whole array thing with sql

Answer (score 0):

If you are practicing the use of loops to do things one at a time (not a good approach for this task!) you can replace your calls to `put_line` with `insert` statements, something like

```
...
  update employees set salary = 1.05 * salary where employee_id = coduri(i);
...
```

The beauty of PL/SQL is that you can embed such plain-SQL statements directly within PL/SQL code, no need for preparation of any kind.

After you are done with the updates, you will need to `commit` for the changes to be committed - usually after the procedure, not within it.

Alternatively, if you want a single `update` (with an `in` condition), you will need to define the varray table at the schema level, not within the anonymous block (or procedure). This is because the `update` statement is a SQL statement, which can't "see" locally defined data types. Then, in the `update` statement you will need to use the `table` operator to unwind its members. Something like this:

```
create type tip_cod is varray(20) of number;
/

DECLARE
  coduri tip_cod;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO coduri
  FROM (
    SELECT employee_id
    from   employees
    where  commission_pct IS NULL
    order by salary asc
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM < 6;

update employees set salary = 1.05 * salary
where employee_id in (select * from table(coduri));
END;
/

commit;
```

Notice how the varray type is defined on its own, then it is used in the PL/SQL block. Also don't forget the `commit` at the end.

When you work with collection types, there is also the `member of` predicate, as in `employee_id member of coduri`. Alas, this only works with locally-defined data types; since the varray type must be declared at the schema level (so that it can be used in a SQL statement within the PL/SQL code), you can't use `member of` and you must unwind the array explicitly, with the `table` operator.

Answer (score 0):

There id much more to [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7115C8B6-62F9-496D-BEC3-F7441DFE148A) (Oracle term for array). There are 3 types:

1. Varrays
2. Associative Arrays
3. Nested Tables

If you want to understand collections you **must understand** all 3. (imho: Of the 3 Varrays are the most limited).

Mathguy presents 1 option, "casting" the array as a table, via the TABLE(...) function. I'll present another: Nested Table combined with Bulk Collect/Forall combination to accomplish he update.

```
declare
    type employee_id_att is table of hr.employees.employee_id%type; 
    employee_id_array employee_id_att; 
    
begin
    select employee_id 
      bulk collect 
      into employee_id_array
      from hr.employees
     where commission_pct is null
     order by salary
     fetch first 5 rows only; 
     
     forall emp_indx in 1 ..  employee_id_array.count
        update hr.employees 
           set salary = 1.05 * salary
         where employee_id = employee_id_array(emp_indx);
         
end ; 
/
```

**Take Away**: There is much, much more to collections than defining a LOOP. Spend some time with the documentation and write tests and examine the results. But the important thing when you do not understand *write some code*. It will probably fail, that is good, so write something else. Do not be afraid of errors/ exceptions, in development they are friend. And if there is something you cannot understand then post a specific question. Be prepared to show several failed attempts; that will give the community an idea of your thinking and whether you are on the correct path or not.